# How to drive paralleled mosfets with a microcontroller?

Tags: mosfet, switches, dc, parallel, mosfet-driver

I want to make a DC switch with mosfets as follow:
[image: Mosfet Paralleling]

Now I want to know does this circuit work with reliability?
And I want a circuit between avr microcontroller and this circuit to drive the mosfets to switch current.
Frequency of switch is very low about 10 switch in one hour.
In fact the 60 resistor is a heater that has 22uH inductance.
Thank you in advance for your helpfulness.
Best regards.

Comment: I don't think you need the four diodes. Presumably it's a DC application and the 240V input isn't AC - just double checking.

Comment: Why do you need 4 MOSFETS? the IRF 460 is rated for 21A and there are plenty of others with even higher current rating

Comment: Can your microprocessor output source more than 5mA at 5V? - the gate threshold for the IRF460 is 4V, so this will not work reliably with 3.3V logic

Comment: If the gate threshold is 4V then you'll need more like 10V (not 5V) to reliably turn the FETs fully on.

Comment: the 4 diodes are for reverse polarity protection, because may polarity of 240 V be reverse connected.

Comment: My MCU finally can to provide 5V  on output ports but this amount is not adequate to turn on mosfet completely. I want to turn on mosfet with 10-12 V .

Answer (score 2):

I can't even guess what you think the four diodes in series with the FETs are doing.

There is little point to the 470 Ω gate resistors, especially with such a high value.

Yes, you can parallel MOSFETs, and you can use parallel drivers or drive them all from the same driver.  The gate of a MOSFET looks mostly like a capacitor to the rest of the circuit.  It therefore takes current to switch.  If the driver has to switch 4 together, it needs to provide 4x the current to switch them all in the same time.

Since you are switching very slowly, the total switch transition time isn't much of a issue.  You therefore don't need a super high current driving each base.

You didn't provide a link to the FET datasheet, so we don't know what the gate voltage needs to be.  However, since you're switching 240 V, I'll assume the gates need to be driven to 12 V or so.  A microcontroller can't do that directly.  There are many low side FET gate driver chips available that take a logic signal in and produce the gate voltage out.  One of these between the micro and the four gates wired together would do fine.

One problem will be producing the 12 V for the gate driver.  Some drivers will do this themselves, but rely on regular switching for the internal charge pump to work.  Some have free running oscillators to run their charge pumps, and can be held at fixed levels indefinitely.

You will probably be better off making the 12 V yourself.  The best strategy depends on what power voltages you already have available.  If you only have the 3.3 V that runs the micro, then a small boost converter that makes 12 V from the 3.3 V is probably the simplest.  This boost converter doesn't need to supply much current since you are switching so slowly.  It does need to have a decent size capacitor on its output to handle the sudden but short-lived current demand when the gates are being switched from low to high.

Comment: Thanks, I have 12V power supply. and the 4 diodes are for reverse polarity protection, because may polarity of 240 V  be reverse connected.